# How to add taxes and cardholder name to Charge?

Tags: payment-gateway, charge

Im trying to setup Subscription using Charge.
But in test mode i havent yet found a way how I can include taxes and cardholders name to actual form and receipt.

I tried to look at addon dokumentation but only what i found was the tag for cardholders name. I did try to use text input and run one test, but again, in Stripe dashboard, name was missing.

About taxes i didnt find anything but that is a must to include.

Any advice would be more than welcome, thank you.

Comment: data-stripe="name" is the answer for cardholders name. For taxes I have not yet found a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Stripe as a payment processor doesn't really care about shipping or tax related information because they try to make it easy to charge your customers.

> Our current goal is to make it easy for you to accept any payment from
>   your customers. We focus on providing a simple interface through which
>   you can create charges.
>
> ```
> With that in mind, we don’t currently calculate any sales tax, VAT, tips, shipping, or other costs for your one-time charges.
> ```
>
> Instead, we will let you specify the final amount you’d like your
>   customer to be charged, so you can include the total price in the
>   `amount` field.

Having said that the best approach is to use [Stripe Metadata](https://stripe.com/docs/api#metadata) feature to pass taxes, shipping cost and anything else that you need to Stripe. Once you pass the metadata you can then use that data in custom reports and any and all metadata is included with Stripe Exports.

The docs are a little light for Charge's [Meta tags](http://squarebit.co.uk/software/expressionengine/charge/docs/meta-information) but Joel has taken the time to create a very robust [example template](https://gist.github.com/joelbradbury/69f9ece70b1a285a5cfb) that you can look through.

In your template you will need to calculate the taxes and whatever else you might need with some javascript or template logic then submit that along with your order to Stripe.

Comment: Oh. So if I have lets say $50 subscription, I just can charge the amount but sure how I can add the tax part to receipt. I can calculate the tax myself, but how to add it to meta so possible client gets an receipt that shows the paid amount and the tax with details. Something like this: - tax 24% $12,34 = Total $50 . In our country receipt that has no taxes showed up, its not a valid receipt so I need that to be included to it. And thank you for the  reply.

Comment: something like `<input type="hidden" name="meta[tax_percent]" value="24"> <input type="hidden" name="meta[tax_value]" value="12.34">` then in your template you will want to call the Stripe Meta fields

Comment: Charge's Meta tags ( http://squarebit.co.uk/software/expressionengine/charge/docs/meta-information ). Example template ( https://gist.github.com/joelbradbury/69f9ece70b1a285a5cfb )

Comment: I try to look and test this. Seems hard task to include automatic calculate process.

Comment: You are going to need some JavaScript in your templates or to build the cart and calculation functionality in an extension to extend Charge

Comment: Ah so. Oh well, not within my skills, bummer. Thanks for that info.

Comment: In that case something like Store has cart, checkout, shipping, and taxes functionality built in